# joining data from 3 tables using inner selects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('/uploads/profiles/', user_uuid, '.jpg') as profile_pic,
(select count(*) from `good_reads_comments` b where a.id=b.parent_id) as child_post_count 
FROM `good_reads_comments` a,
(select count(*) from `comment_likes` c where a.id=c.comment_id) as 
 post_like_count 
FROM `comment_likes` a 
WHERE good_read_uuid='123456789' 
AND parent_id=0 
ORDER BY d_date
```

My problem is in the syntax.
without the second select

`((select count(*) from comment_likes c where a.id=c.comment_id) as post_like_count FROM comment_likes a)` the query works fine.

please help

Comment: You have 2 `FROM` in your outer query

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need below

```
 SELECT *, CONCAT('/uploads/profiles/', user_uuid, '.jpg') as profile_pic,
 (select count(*) from `good_reads_comments` b where a.id=b.parent_id) as 
child_post_count,
(select count(*) from `comment_likes` c where a.id=c.comment_id) as  post_like_count    
    FROM `comment_likes` a           
    WHERE good_read_uuid='123456789' 
    AND parent_id=0 
    ORDER BY d_date
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT *, 
   CONCAT('/uploads/profiles/', user_uuid, '.jpg') as profile_pic, 
   count(b.parent_id) as child_post_count, 
   count(c.comment_id) from comment_likes as post_like_count 
FROM good_reads_comments a 
JOIN good_reads_comments b on a.id = b.parent_id 
JOIN comment_likes on a.id = c.comment_id 
WHERE good_read_uuid='123456789' 
   AND parent_id=0 
ORDER BY d_date
```